# How can I calculate the mean and variance of a linearly transformed random variable?

Tags: mean, data-transformation, standard-deviation, linear

Say I have a random variable $x$, with mean $\mu_x=35$ and standard deviation $\sigma_x=10$. I want to linearly transform $x$ to $y$ according to the formula $y=a+bx$ so that $\mu_y=100$ and $\sigma_y=15$, choosing values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy these properties.

I know the formulas to calculate mean and standard deviation of a single random variable, but I can't figure out how to adapt them to a linear transformation of a random variable, particularly for situations where I only have a mean and variance for a distribution and not the underlying data.

Comment: And....why would you? Isn't it just simpler to transform your variables and then find the mean and standard deviation of the transformed variables?

Comment: I could do that for a specific example, but I would like to have a general rule for various linear transformations, particularly for situations where I only have a mean and variance for a distribution and not the underlying data.

Comment: Then say so, for clarity, and maybe someone will answer.

Comment: Begin with [linearity of expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=linearity+expectation).  If that doesn't completely resolve the question, then please indicate where you are stuck in the derivation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since y = a + b*x, we have following.

E[y] = E[a + b*x] = a + b*E(x). Thus, y's mean = a + b * (x's mean).

E[y^2] = E[(a + b*x)^2] = a^2 + 2*a*b*E[x] + b^2*E[x^2].

(E[y])^2 = (a + b*E(x))^2 = a^2 + 2*a*b*E[x] + b^2*(E[x])^2.

var(y) = E[y^2] - (E[y])^2 = b^2*(E[x^2] - (E[x])^2) = b^2*Var(x).

Conclusions:

(1) y's mean = a + b * (x's mean).

(2) y's variance = b^2 * (x's variance).

Comment: Very helpful and clear, thanks!